# Electron framework desktop app with AWS S3 Sync

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying to find a solution for this but I need to ask you all. Do you know if there is a windows desktop application out there which would put (real time sync) objects from a local folder into predefined AWS S3 bucket? This could work just one way - upload from local to s3.

Comment: https://www.cloudberrylab.com/drive/amazon-s3.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Setting it up**

- Insall AWS cli https://aws.amazon.com/cli/ for windows.
- Through AWS website/console. Create an IAM user with a strict policy that allows access only to the required S3 bucket.
- Run `aws configure` in powershell or cmd and set up the **region**, **access key** and **secrect key** for the IAM user that you created.
- Test if your set up is correct by running `aws s3 ls` in the command line and verify you see a list of your account S3 buckets.
- If not, then you probably configured IAM permissions incorrectly, you might need ListBuckets on all of S3 too.

**How to sync examples**

- `aws s3 sync path/to/yourfolder s3://mybucket/`
- `aws s3 sync path/to/yourfolder s3://mybucket/images/`
- `aws s3 sync path/to/yourfolder s3://mybucket/images/ --delete` deletes files on S3 that are no longer available on your local path.

Not sure what this has to do with electron but you could set up a trigger on your application to invoke these commands. For example, in atom.io or VS code, you could bind this to saving a document on "ctrl+s".

If you are programming an application using Electron then you should consider using AWS JavaScript SDK instead of the AWS CLI but that is a whole different story.

And lastly, back up your files somewhere else before trying to use possibly destructive commands such as sync until you get a feeling of how they work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it has to be an installable app which allows average user to do this.